# Given convex differentiable function $h: R^m \to R$, what is geometric interpretation of $h(x)/\|\nabla h(x)\|$ vis à vis the level-set $h=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $h:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ be a convex diifferentiable function and define $C_h := \{x \in \mathbb R^m \mid h(x) = 0\}$, assumed to be non-empty.

> **Question.** Given $x \in \mathbb R^m$ such that $\nabla h(x) \ne 0$, is there any geometric interpretation of the quantity $\omega_h(x) := (h(x))_+/\|\nabla h(x)\|$ vis à vis the set $C_h$ ?

**Motivation.** In the linear case where $h(x) = v^Tx$ for some unit-vector $v \in \mathbb R^m$, one has

- $C_h = v^\perp$, the hyperplane perpendicular to $v$.
- $\|\nabla h(x)\| = \|v\| = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^m$, and so $\omega_h(x) = (h(x))_+ = (v^Tx)_+$, which is the distance of $x$ from $C_h$.

Comment: There's no need for $C_h$ to be nonempty, for example $h(x) = \|x\|^2 + 1$

Comment: You may assume $C_h \ne \emptyset$. I'm not sure I understand the phrasing of your comment...

Comment: Point just was that as originally phrased your question did not rule out trivial examples.

Answer (score 1):

Given a unit-vector $v \in \mathbb S_{m-1} := \{v \in \mathbb R^m \mid \|v\| = 1\}$, let $\mathscr L_v := \{x + tv \mid
t \ge 0\} \subseteq  \mathbb R^m$ be the ray generated by $v$ and starting at $x$. The
distance of $x$ from $C_h$ can be written as
$$
r_h(x) := d(x,C_h) := \inf_{x' \in C_h}\|x'-x\| = \inf_{v
  \in \mathbb S_{m-1}}\inf_{x' \in
  \mathscr L_v \cap C_h}\|x'-x\|.
$$

Now, by definition, $x' \in \mathscr L_v \cap C_h$ if and only if
there exists a time $t \in [0,\infty)$ such that $x' = x + tv$ and $h(x') = 0$.
Thus,
\begin{eqnarray}
  r_h(x) = \inf\{t \mid (v,t) \in \mathbb S_{m-1} \times [0,\infty),\; h(x + tv) = 0\}.
  \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

### The convex case

If $h$ is convex and differentiable, then for all $(v,t) \in \mathbb S_{m-1} \times
[0,\infty)$ one has
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \begin{split}
    h(x+tv) &\ge h(x) + t\nabla h(x)^Tv\ge h(x) - t\|\nabla h(x)\|,\\
    -h(x+tv) &\le -h(x) - t\nabla h(x)^Tv \le -h(x) + t\|\nabla h(x)\|,    
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
where we have used Cauchy-Schwarz to reach the final term of each chain of
inequalities. Combining the above inequalities and (1) one
computes
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \begin{split}
r_h(x) &\ge \inf\{t \ge 0 \mid h(x) -
t\|\nabla h(x)\|\le 0\} = \frac{\max(h(x),0)}{\|\nabla h(x)\|},\\
r_h(x) &\ge \inf\{t \ge 0 \mid -h(x) +
t\|\nabla h(x)\|\ge 0\} = \frac{\max(-h(x), 0)}{\|\nabla h(x)\|},
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
We have thus proved

> **Theorem.**
> *If $h:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ is convex differentiable, we have*
> \begin{eqnarray}
>   r_h(x) \ge \frac{|h(x)|}{\|\nabla h(x)\|},\;\forall x \in \mathbb R^m
> \end{eqnarray}

### Lipschitz case

If we instead assume $h$ Lipschitz continuous (but not necessarily convex), then $|h(x + tv) -  h(x)| \le
Lt$ for all $(v,t) \in \S_{m-1} \times [0,\infty)$. Using (1), we may then compute
\begin{eqnarray}
  \begin{split}
r_h(x) &\ge \inf\{t \ge 0\mid h(x) - tL \ge 0\} =
\frac{\max(h(x),0)}{L},\\
r_h(x) &\ge \inf\{t \ge 0\mid h(x) + tL \ge 0\} =
\frac{\max(-h(x),0)}{L}.
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
Putting things together, we get

> **Theorem.** *If $h:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ is $L$-Lipschitz, then we have*
> \begin{eqnarray}
>   r_h(x) \ge \frac{|h(x)|}{L},\;\forall x \in \mathbb R^m.
> \end{eqnarray}